# Validar un textbox en C#

Tags: c#

Como puedo hacer para que mi textbox solo acepte el 0 y el 1. O que solo acepte un character.
Este es el codigo que tengo.

```
private void press(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
```

El que me pueda ayudar , gracias.

Comment: *O que solo acepte un character*: ¿Que quieres decir con esto? ¿Que solo puedes ingresar un solo `0` o `1`? ¿No puedes ingresar `0101010` por ejemplo?

Comment: si pero ya lo logre desde la interfaz

Answer (score 1):

En las propiedades del textbox: MaxLength = 1

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            //Solo aceptamos números: 0,1
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "[0-1]"))
            {
               //Tu codigo aquí
            }else{
                 MessageBox.Show("Hey brother, por favor considera que este campo solo admite 0,1");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Algo un poco drástico, ¿No? ¡Jajaja!

Comment: un poquito :D Por cierto, voy editando la respuesta, necesitamos un else para avisar al usuario que debe ser reemplazado por otro que sí sepa entender el sistema hahahaha, broma, vamos haciendo un mensaje bien user-friendly

Comment: Parece buena respuesta, solo que está mal indentada.

Comment: @ArtEze todos somos responsables por como indentamos nuestro código :P

Comment: @NaCl Ahora veo que la pregunta está igual, no dije nada.

Comment: el compilador igual funciona :v

Answer (score 1):

¿Has probado utilizar expresiones regulares?

```
    private void press(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString(), @"[a-zA-Z01]?"))
        {                
            //TODO
        }
    }
```

Esto admitiría carácteres de la *a* a la *z* en minúscula y mayúscula, junto con los números 0 y 1.

Comment: como lo puedo poner para que solo acepte el 0 y el 1??

Comment: Reemplaza lo que está entre los corchetes por 01, quedando @"[01]?"

Comment: Aun asi me permite ingresar letras

Comment: como puedo hacer para que me permita solo diguitar 12 por ejemplo?       con ese codigo que usted me envoi --> @"[a-zA-Z01]?"

Comment: Para restringirlo a 12 caracteres, puedes reemplazar el signo de interrogación por el número deseado: @"[a-zA-Z01]{12}" . Pero si lo que quiere es reconocer el número 12, puede usar @"[1][2]"

Answer (score 1):

Hola lo puedes solucionar personalizando un control `TextBox`, he personalizado un control `TextBox` que te valida el ingreso de números, letras, decimales.

[TextBox-ComboBox personalizado](https://github.com/PedroAvila/TextBox-ComboBox)

Ahí puedes descargar el proyecto de ejemplo para que vea como funciona, debe agregar la dll `GlobalTech.TextBoxControl.dll` como referencia al proyecto y también al ToolBox para que pueda utilizar estos controles.